# Vue 2.0.3 setting option value not working with :value="x" or v-bind:value="x"

Tags: html-select, vue.js

https://jsfiddle.net/53jprgse/

I'm not able to get dynamic select option value attributes set using Vue 2.0.3 and **`:value`** or **`v-bind:value`** bindings. No option values are being set when I use these.

I have to add the static html **`value=""`** or **`value="some value"`** attribute to get option value attributes to render their dynamic values.

My data set is a simple array of strings.

This is illustrated by inspecting the select elements at the fiddle above.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here? Seems like this should be very straight forward.

Comment: not sure what's the issue. Selected county always shown next to select, so what's wrong?

Comment: I'm not getting option value attributes set on the top two selects. Inspect the select elements, the top two don't have <option value="county name"> option values.  Inspect the bottom two select elements (with the yellow highlight), those two selects have <option value="county name"> option values.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the DOM to actually have the `value` attribute set by `v-bind` you have to actually add the `value` attribute (doesn't matter what it says).

So, in your first 2 selects you basically had this:

```
<div>
  <p>
    :value="county"
  </p>
  <select v-model="filterByCounty">
    <option value="">Filter by county...</option>
    <option v-for="county in counties" :value="county">
      {{ county }}
    </option>
  </select>
  {{ selected_county }}
</div>
```

If you just add a `value` to the `<option>` it will work as you'd like:

```
<option v-for="county in counties" :value="county" value="">
```